# Android pass extras to extended class

Tags: android

As the title says, I want to know if it is possible to pass extras to an extended class.

Imagine this situation:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
        super.onCreate(sis);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ....
    }
}

public class MyMainClass extends MyClass{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Here I would like to pass some extras to MyClass

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to pass extras to `MyClass`

Comment: Yes you can pass extras when you call Intent

Comment: When you call the Intent for starting that activity you can pass those extras.

Comment: Sorry but fixed the code. `MyMainClass` extends `MyClass` and not `Activity`. Want to pass extras from `MyMainClass` to my extended `MyClass`

Comment: Hope it will work because the Most parent class extends Activity..Better you can do that by this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/29257787/4693713. And you can get the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MyMainClass.this, MyClass.class);
 i.putExtra("extra", extra);
 startActivity(i);
```

and you can get that extra back using

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String extra = extras.getString("extra");
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but fixed the code. `MyMainClass` extends `MyClass` and not `Activity`. Want to pass extras from `MyMainClass` to my extended `MyClass`

Comment: no problem, the code should still work. Have you tried it ?